# How to disable automatic hyperlinking?

Tags: hyperref

How do I tell the system to treat emails and hyperlinks as a pure text and not to create hyperlinks from its contents, so that I use hyperref package commands explicitly if I want my text to be hyperlinked?

Comment: `\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}`

Comment: @HarishKumar This hides links (suppressing color and border, but they are still there), the question mentions "not to create hyperlinks". But who knows? Mybe hiding them is enough for the OP?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: It was a wild guess as I didn't understand the question properly :)

Comment: @HarishKumar It does not help.

Comment: Welcome! Why don't you just not load `hyperref` and just load `url` so that you can format them and not have them as links. This is what I use mostly, in fact.

Comment: Note that it is hard to see how *any* system could treat hyperlinks without creating hyperlinks from them. I mean, I guess that technically, if they are already hyperlinks, the system might not *create* hyperlinks from them. But that would be an extremely odd thing to care about.

Comment: @cfr It seems like not loading the hyperref package does not help. If I type "alice@bob.com" I just want that to be a text and not a hyperlink (mailto:alice@bob.com).

Comment: Wait, sorry, are you saying that if you put the text, `alice@bob.com`, no command around it, in your source file, it displays as a hyperlink?  Both with and without `hyperref`?

Comment: @Lorehead: Nope, I think it's the Reader's feature to recognize a mail adresse and changing the cursor?

Comment: Several PDF viewers have heuristics for finding URL or email addresses in the text. It has nothing to do with TeX, it will happen also if you make a PDF out of any word processor file. If you don't use `hyperref`, `pdflatex` will *not* make hyperlinks.

Comment: Right.  That’s what I’m asking.  Or to put it another way: does the same thing happen in a different PDF reader?

Comment: @egreg I tried to open the file with the Preview app - same thing.

Comment: @AndrejsIgumenovs Exactly what I said: it's the viewer trying to be smart.

Comment: @egreg I doubt so as the TexShop PDF Viewer does the same thing.

Comment: @AndrejsIgumenovs This only confirms what I said: TeXShop and Preview use the same Apple PDF libraries; both try to isolate URI from the text and there's nothing you can do.

Comment: @AndrejsIgumenovs: Can you provide the community with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that replicates the result? Also, include an image that shows how your reading is currently rendering content as hyperlinks.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't load `hyperref`, LaTeX will *not* make hyperlinks. However, viewers such as Preview, Skim and the TeXShop one use the Apple PDF libraries and, unfortunately, try to find URL and email addresses in the text.

Compiling the simple example file

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
alice@bob.com
\end{document}
```

will show a `mailto:` link when the PDF is viewed with Preview or Skim, but not with Adobe Reader. I don't think it's possible to disable this annoying feature in Apple PDFKit based viewers.

Comment: That's true about your document. But if I remove the _hyperref_ reference in my document, Adobe Reader still has the link. But yeah, probably it's on the viewer's side and not because of the TeX.

Answer (score 1):

## An elegant solution using hyperref

```
\usepackage[implicit=false, bookmarks=false]{hyperref}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\nolinkurl` on the links you want to hide.

Comment: Does this work for hyperlinks in the ToC, for example?

Comment: It does not help.

Comment: `hyperindex=false, hyperfootnotes=false` option, I think?